# Shinydashboars tabItems not working properly

Tags: r, shiny, menuitem, dashboard, tabitem

I am testing the shinydashboard package and I just can't figure out what is happening in a particular case. My dashboard has 4 tabItems (sorry it's in Dutch):

- Programma
- Deelnemers
- Notulen
- Overige

The dashboard loads properly, but the content of tabItem four ("Overige") is shown beneath the content of "Notulen".

The code of the App is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(markdown)
library(DT)


# Simple header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Economencongres")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sidebar <- ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Programma 2015",
        tabName = "Programma",
        icon = icon("info-circle")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Deelnemers",
        tabName = "Deelnemers",
        icon = icon("users")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Notulen",
        tabName = "Notulen",
        icon = icon("file-text")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Presentaties",
        tabName = "Presentaties",
        icon = icon("file-movie-o")
      )
    )
  )

# Compose dashboard body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    # First tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Programma",
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          width = 12,
          title = "",
          id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
          tabPanel(
            "Agenda",
            h2(""),
            width = 12,
            h2("Agenda d.d. 25-03-2015"),
            includeHTML("Agenda.html")
          ),
          tabPanel(
            "Presentatie ABN AMRO",
            h2("Danny van Brummelen"),
            tags$iframe(
            width="800",
            height="600",
            seamless="seamless",
            src="http://www.allmoocs.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ABN.pdf"
            )
          ),
          tabPanel(
            "Presentatie HAN BKMER",
            h2("Witek ten Hove"),
            h4("Klik op de presentatie en navigeer met de pijlen op het toetsenbord"),
            tags$iframe(
            width="1000",
            height="800",
            seamless="seamless",
            src="http://witusj.github.io/Economencongres/economen25032015.html"
            )
          )
        ) # End of tabBox
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Second tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Deelnemers",
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          width = 12,
          title = "",
          id = "tabset2", height = "250px",
          tabPanel("Kaart",
                   h2(""),
                   tags$iframe(
                     width="800",
                     height="600",
                     seamless="seamless",
                     src="http://www.allmoocs.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/map.html"
                   )
          ),
          tabPanel("Lijst",
                   DT::dataTableOutput('deeln')
          )
        ) # End of tabBox
      ) # End of fluidRow,
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Third tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Notulen",
      fluidRow(
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt10.md")
        ),
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt11.md")
        ),
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt12.md")
        )
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Fourth tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Presentaties",
      fluidRow(
        box(
          h2("Hello")
        )
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ) # End of tabItem
  ) ## End tabItems
) ## End dashboardBody




# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "purple")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  source('map.R')
  output$deeln <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(ec[,c(2:8)])

 })
}


# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Must be my ingnorance, but it's driving me nuts!

UPDATE: I cleaned up the code a bit, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! The problem seems to be caused by the .md files. I don't know why but they prevent the closure of the tabItem. The weird thing though is that it first seemed to work in the RStudio environment and now it doesn't. However after deployment on my [AWS Shiny Server](http://ec2-54-76-89-164.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/EC/2015/) everything looks OK. Weird things are happening here!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(markdown)
library(DT)


# Simple header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Economencongres")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sidebar <- ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Programma 2015",
        tabName = "Programma",
        icon = icon("info-circle")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Deelnemers",
        tabName = "Deelnemers",
        icon = icon("users")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Notulen",
        tabName = "Notulen",
        icon = icon("file-text")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Presentaties",
        tabName = "Presentaties",
        icon = icon("file-movie-o")
      )
    )
  )

# Compose dashboard body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(

    # First tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Programma",
      fluidRow(
        box(
          width = 12,
          h2("Agenda d.d. 25-03-2015"),
          includeHTML("Agenda.html")
        ) 
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Second tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Deelnemers",
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          width = 12,
          title = "",
          id = "tabset2", height = "250px",
          tabPanel("Kaart",
                   h2(""),
                   tags$iframe(
                     width="800",
                     height="600",
                     seamless="seamless",
                     src="http://www.allmoocs.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/map.html"
                   )
          ),
          tabPanel("Lijst",
                   DT::dataTableOutput('deeln')
          )
        ) # End of tabBox
      ) # End of fluidRow,
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Third tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Notulen",
      fluidRow(
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt10.md")
        ),
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt11.md")
        ),
        box(
          h2(""),
          width = 12,
          includeMarkdown("txt12.md")
        )
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ), # End of tabItem

    # Fourth tab content
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Presentaties",
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          width = 12,
          title = "",
          id = "tabset1",
          height = "250px",
          tabPanel(
              "Presentatie ABN AMRO",
              h2("Danny van Brummelen"),
              box(
              tags$iframe(
                width="800",
                height="600",
                seamless="seamless",
                src="http://www.allmoocs.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ABN.pdf"
              )
            )
          ),
          tabPanel(
              "Presentatie HAN BKMER",
              h2("Witek ten Hove"),
              h4("Klik op de presentatie en navigeer met de pijlen op het toetsenbord"),
              box(
              tags$iframe(
                width="1000",
                height="800",
                seamless="seamless",
                src="http://witusj.github.io/Economencongres/economen25032015.html"
              )
            )
          )
        ) # End of tabBox
      ) # End of fluidRow
    ) # End of tabItem
  ) ## End tabItems
) ## End dashboardBody




# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "purple")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  source('map.R')
  output$deeln <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(ec[,c(2:8)])

  })
}


# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server
```

)