# shinydashboard tabItems not working

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a simple shiny dashboard that has four tabs in the side menu, and for some reason, when I build the shiny app, clicking on the side menu does not show me a new page, and the content of tab2 just appends itself to tab1.

While searching stackoverflow showed me this question: [Shinydashboars tabItems not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421596/shinydashboars-tabitems-not-working-properly?s=10|55.2601), the answer doesn't apply to me since I'm not using rmd, and i don't plan to host it to a AWS server.

Here is the code for reference:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Study Dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Overall Objectives", tabName = "objectives"),
  menuItem("Wellpad Operator", tabName = "wellpad_operator"),
  menuItem("Wastewater Expert", tabName = "wastewater_expert"),
  menuItem("Freshwater Expert", tabName = "freshwater_expert"),
  menuItem("Environmental Impact", tabName = "environ_impact")
)
),
dashboardBody(
#Tab 1 Objective View
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "objectives", 
          h2("Overall Objectives"),
          fluidRow(
            box(
              title = "Overall Objective Comparison", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
              plotOutput("objective_plot")
            ),
            box(
              title = "Cost Category Breakdown", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
              plotOutput("costbreakdown_plot")
            ),
            box(
              title = "Decision Variables", width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
              tableOutput("decision_table"))
          ))
),

#Tab 2 Wellpad Decision
tabItem(tabName = "wellpad_operator", 
        h2("Wellpad Operator") 
        ),

#Tab 3 Wastewater Expert
tabItem(tabName = "wastewater_expert",
        h2("Wastewater Expert")
        ),

#Tab 4 Freshwater Expert
tabItem(tabName = "freshwater_expert",
        h2("Freshwater Expert")
        ),

#Tab 5 Environmental Damages
tabItem(tabName = "environ_impact",
        h2("Environmental Impact"))
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
#server side code that generates the plots
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all your `tabItem` inside `tabItems`. Try this:

```
dashboardBody(
    #Tab 1 Objective View
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "objectives", 
              h2("Overall Objectives"),
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = "Overall Objective Comparison", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
                  plotOutput("objective_plot")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Cost Category Breakdown", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
                  plotOutput("costbreakdown_plot")
                ),
                box(
                  title = "Decision Variables", width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
                  tableOutput("decision_table"))
              )),
      #Tab 2 Wellpad Decision
      tabItem(tabName = "wellpad_operator", 
              h2("Wellpad Operator") 
      ),

      #Tab 3 Wastewater Expert
      tabItem(tabName = "wastewater_expert",
              h2("Wastewater Expert")
      ),

      #Tab 4 Freshwater Expert
      tabItem(tabName = "freshwater_expert",
              h2("Freshwater Expert")
      ),

      #Tab 5 Environmental Damages
      tabItem(tabName = "environ_impact",
              h2("Environmental Impact"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow that was a stupid mistake on my end. Teaches me to not track my brackets properly. Thank you for digging this out for me!

Comment: happens to me all the time with Shiny! Corresponding brackets can be so far from each other...